# The configuration key "defaults" is unsupported for definition "nelmio_cors"

Tags: symfony, cors, api-platform.com

I'm trying to enable CORS for my api (I'm using Symfony 4.2 + api_platform)

I have installed NelmiosCors

```
composer req "nelmio/cors-bundle"
```

Added it to Kernel.php

```
$bundles = array(
    new Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle(),
);
```

And added this to services.yaml

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type']
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth', 'Content-Type']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
        '^/':
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['^http://localhost:[0-9]+']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth', 'Content-Type']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
            hosts: ['^api\.']
```

But when I do server:run I get an error:

```
In FileLoader.php line 166:
!!
!!    The configuration key "defaults" is unsupported for definition "nelmio_cors
!!    " in "/mnt/c/dev/api/config/services.yaml". Allowed configuration keys are
!!    "alias", "parent", "class", "shared", "synthetic", "lazy", "public", "abstr
!!    act", "deprecated", "factory", "file", "arguments", "properties", "configur
!!    ator", "calls", "tags", "decorates", "decoration_inner_name", "decoration_p
!!    riority", "autowire", "autoconfigure", "bind" in /mnt/c/dev/api/config/serv
!!    ices.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/mnt/c/dev/api/config/services.yaml
!!    ").
!!
!!
!!  In YamlFileLoader.php line 813:
!!
!!    The configuration key "defaults" is unsupported for definition "nelmio_cors
!!    " in "/mnt/c/dev/api/config/services.yaml". Allowed configuration keys are
!!    "alias", "parent", "class", "shared", "synthetic", "lazy", "public", "abstr
!!    act", "deprecated", "factory", "file", "arguments", "properties", "configur
!!    ator", "calls", "tags", "decorates", "decoration_inner_name", "decoration_p
!!    riority", "autowire", "autoconfigure", "bind".
```

I followed NelmiosCors guide + api_platform guide, Now I don't know what I can do.

Some help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Symfony 4.x, you must use a separated configuration for all your bundle but not inside the service.yaml

Create a file named **nelmio_cors.yaml** indide ***config/package/*** and put all your nelmio_cors configuration!